# Min-Max Sigma at the same time?

Tags: notation

I'm reading a research paper, and came across this: $$\text{min}\,\,\text{max}_{\forall i,j\in\lbrace{1,...,n}\rbrace}\frac{\sum_{f=1}^p\mathbf{A}_{ij}^f\cdot MS_f}{\tau\cdot\mathbf{B}_{ij}}.$$

Requesting for clarification what does the left side of this equation mean, I see both max and min at the same time...

Comment: Presumably, you have a set of sets.  Find the max of each of the inner sets.  Find the minimum of those maximums.  For example, $min(max(\{\{1,5,\color{red}{8}\},\{2,4,\color{red}{6}\},\{10,\color{red}{20}\}\})) = min(\{8,6,20\})=6$.  As for your specific case, it is unclear without more context what sort of objects these $A_{ij}^f$'s or $MS_f$'s are.

Comment: This notation is indeed strange. I don’t know what the $\forall$ in the subscript of $\max$ is doing, for example. Ignoring the $\forall$ (which is the only somewhat reasonable explanation I see), I can think of two interpretations: Either the $i$s belong to the $\min$ and the $j$s to the $\max$ (i.e. for every $i$ calculate the maximum the fraction can attain when varying $j$, then take the minimum of those maxima), or $i, j$ both belong to $\max$ and there is another unspecified variable for the $\min$ (maybe $f$?). It’s hard to tell without more context.

Comment: The '∀' is basically 'for all' or 'for any'... In this context, it reads, for all values of i, j in set {1,...,n}...

About the other contexts, you guys can simply assume just a boolean matrix or binary matrix for what is in the right of minmax∀i,j∈{1,...,n}

Meaning, I'd be okay if I find the meaning of the following-

min max∀i,j∈{1,...,n} Aij